# Мобильные запросы Instagram как сгенерировать signed_body?

Tags: javascript

У меня есть запросы в Fiddler`e там с десктоп программы отправляется

> signed_body=01935b90095f78316ba32a14d4148e94952fb78e8c578c8437581df8f9ed5b26

значение signed_body генерируется программой вот хотел бы узнать кто может помочь с этим может кто работал уже с мобильными запросами instagram?

Comment: Уточните вопрос, что вам нужно сделать?

Comment: Нашел вот тут пример скрипта для php 
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803533/php-instagram-uploader-%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-instagram-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-php/804282#804282

Мне нужно отправить запрос а для запроса нужен signed_body а она генерируется вот хотел узнать каким образом

Comment: Нашел тут способ генерировать https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803533/php-instagram-uploader-%D0%9F%D1%83%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B2-instagram-%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7-php/804282#804282

function GenerateSignature($data) {
     return hash_hmac('sha256', $data, 'b4a23f5e39b5929e0666ac5de94c89d1618a2916');
}

не могу понять какие данные писать вместо $data